# problemas para poder establecer puntos de interrupcion en VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-basic

Buenas gente cuando trato de ejecutar un punto de interrupción me sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busque por internet algún tipo de solución pero no he podido resolverlo

Comment: Solo deten la ejecucion añade el punto de interrupcion e intentanta nuevamente. Si persiste el probelma limpia la solucion y dale un rebuild.